# tmux - shortcut not responding

Tags: tmux

Until a few days ago, tmux was working fine.

Suddenly, I don't know what my colleague did, but the shortcuts stopped working.

We're both using tmux on a remote server (two different sessions), but no session works now.

I mean, we can attach them (`tmux a -t name` works), but then, the shortcut doesn't work.

If I do `Ctrl + a, d`, it just writes `d` to the terminal. I tried with the original shortcut (`Ctrl + b`) but no change.

My tmux.conf is clearly taken into account, since if I do `tmux new -s someName`, I get all the status bar and stuff. The initialization shortcut doesn't work however.

Any idea of what could cause this?

Comment: What does `tmux list-keys` show?

Comment: @cYrus The normal list of shortcuts available. What's not working *in* tmux is the "Enable tmux commands" shortcut, whatever it's called. Do you want a copy paste of `tmux list-keys`?

Comment: If that list contains the shortcuts that you're expecting that's ok. Just check for the usual `set-option -g prefix C-a` in your configuration file.

Comment: I checked it, and it's ok. This conf worked fine until a few days ago...

Comment: @cYrus If you're interested, I added an answer to add the debugging commands I used :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks to @ccxCZ on #tmux@freenode.net, I could find what was the problem.

Using the following:

```
tmux show-options -g | grep prefix
```

Showed me that the prefix was:

```
prefix `
```

Testing it, it was indeed this. I don't know how it turned out this way.

Since my tmux.conf was right, I just had to do:

```
tmux source /etc/tmux.conf
```

And the prefix was set back to the right way.